# while ( *(mychar++)) when will it stop

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I have a following code:

```c
void prepareInput(char* s){
    while ( *(s++) ){
        if(*s == ' ' || *s == '\n')
            *s = '\0';
    }
    return;
}
```

What will `*(s++)` return that will cause while loop to stop?

Comment: `0`, obviously.

Comment: Yea, silly question

Comment: Note that the body of the loop will *not* see the first character of the string. So if the string starts with a space or newline, it will be still be in the string when the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as other cases, when that expression evaluates to FALSE.

In other words, it's the same as `while ( (*(s++)) != 0 ){.....`.

Basically, it's trying to find the null-terminator for the *string* and the loop will go on until it finds the null terminator ([having a value `0`](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

It's finding the null terminator.

It has ASCII of 0.

Comment: FYI, there is nothing standard called 'Null', it's either 'null', or 'NUL'...